# Execute Python script in oracle SQL*PLUS

Tags: python, oracle, plsql

Can anybody let me know how to execute the python script which is saved as .py file inside oracle sql*PLUS?

Thanks and regards,
Santhosha

Comment: SQL*Plus is a client tool for interacting with an Oracle database. What do you mean by a .py file "inside Oracle sql*PLUS"?

Comment: Oracle support Java, so perhaps you could use [Jython](http://www.jython.org/), an implementation of Python for the JVM, to run your Python code.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [HOST](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve026.htm#i2676105) command to execute an operating system command from within a SQL*Plus script:

```
host python your_script.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run external commands from `sqlplus` by preceding them with a `!`

Example:

```
$ sqlplus /nolog

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Sat Mar 15 15:45:35 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

SQL> !python temp.py
which one do you like ? "run"
run
```